# ASP.NET-MVC-5 dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I’m a newbie to mvc 5 dependency injection,I know that mvc 5 has a default parameterless constructor.But in dependency injection we create a constructor with a parameter, and IOC  containers provide object to the parameter.my question is how does IOC containers like unity make mvc 5 understand the parametered constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic way that it works is that you ask the IoC container for a type ("resolve") and it will use reflection to look for the constructor (for Unity, the one with the most arguments if they are multiple constructors). It will then repeat the process for each of the argument types themselves, like a tree all the way down the dependency graph. Unity will be able to create instances of concrete types automatically but if the constructor uses an interface or abstract type then it needs to know which implementation to use so in these cases, you need to register the type beforehand:

Register:

e.g. `container.RegisterType<IUserHelper, UserHelper>();`

Resolve:

e.g. `container.Resolve<IUserHelper>();`

IOC containers do not work with MVC out of the box but extra libraries exist such as Unity.MVC5 which hook into the MVC pipeline so when MVC tries to create a controller, it uses the IoC container instead of newing up the controller directly (which would fail unless it is parameterless).

Here is an example:

```
public class MyController(IUserHelper userHelper, IRepository repository) : Controller
```

Then we could have:

```
public class MyRepository(IDbContext dbContext) : IRepository
```

and

```
public class  MyDbContext () : IDbContext
```

If we use RegisterType to register the IUserHelper, IRepository and IDbContext then when MVC needs to create the controller, it will be able to build the controller complete with all the dependencies.